# How to use Alt+Tab on Windows to switch to desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, alt-tab

I want to only use `alt+tab` to switch tabs, I consider the desktop a tab.

 How would I enable switching to the desktop?

I saw in this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/352028/windows-10-is-changing-how-alttab-works-here%E2%80%99s-what-you-need-to-know/#:%7E:text=To%20make%20the%20Windows%20Alt,the%20%E2%80%9CWindows%20Only%E2%80%9D%20setting.) that you need to change the option below, however it's nowhere to be seen in my settings menu.

[image: alt+tab_enable]

Also there is this 5 year old [discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/alttab-to-desktop-no-longer-an-option/ea3f5567-7c75-43a2-b1df-3d77bc9987c2?page=3).

Windows version: 2004

Comment: The article you are referencing is about a preview version and it seems this feature didn't make it (yet?) to the production version. For example I lack the tab capabilities of file explorer completely.

Comment: The function to switch Desktops is part of Task View (icon lower left). This is true in V1909, V2004. Windows Insider future versions includes Chromium Edge tabs in Alt-Tab. This appears to be a work in progress.

Comment: @phuclv yep, will close as dup